# How to grab contained space when scraping python using spider

Tags: python, web-scraping

Can anybody help, please?

I am finding it difficult to grab the value of currency units per SDR using my python code below.

The code is working with other URLs, but for this URL, I always get a null result. I don’t understand what is wrong.

I’m using python scrappy spider.
URL: https://www.imf.org/external/np/fin/data/rms_five.aspx

I reviewed the content on the website and found that it contains some spaces.  There are some spaces in the element value:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/GO4BHC8]

Using RSS response and XPath, I get the same result i.e. null

```
def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
        'https://www.imf.org/external/np/fin/data/rms_five.aspx'
        
    ]
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    print(response.url)
        
    #for i in range (1, 24):
    yield {
    'Kurs_imf2': response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/center/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/text()').getall()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, looking only at your ultimate goal (and disregarding your eventual unfortunate choice of tools), here is one way of getting the data from that table, as a dataframe. Once you have the data, you can manipulate it as needed (like stripping the leading/trailing spaces, etc):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://www.imf.org/external/np/fin/data/rms_five.aspx'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')

table_w_data = soup.select_one('div.fancy').select_one('table')
df = pd.read_html(str(table_w_data))[0]
print(df)
```

This will display in terminal:

|  | ('SDRs per Currency unit 2', 'Unnamed: 0_level_1') | ('SDRs per Currency unit 2', 'September 05, 2022') | ('SDRs per Currency unit 2', 'September 02, 2022') | ('SDRs per Currency unit 2', 'September 01, 2022') | ('SDRs per Currency unit 2', 'August 31, 2022') | ('SDRs per Currency unit 2', 'August 30, 2022') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Chinese yuan | nan | 0.111437 | 0.111266 | 0.111474 | 0.110906 |
| 1 | Euro | nan | 0.768586 | 0.768411 | 0.768436 | 0.769353 |
| 2 | Japanese yen | nan | 0.00549178 | 0.00550612 | 0.00554387 | 0.00553607 |
| 3 | U.K. pound | nan | 0.889646 | 0.887851 | 0.892615 | 0.898473 |
| 4 | U.S. dollar | nan | 0.769124 | 0.768104 | 0.768436 | 0.766746 |
| 5 | Algerian dinar | nan | 0.0054812 | 0.00547939 | 0.00547416 | 0.00547027 |
| 6 | Australian dollar | nan | 0.522235 | 0.524922 | 0.530375 | 0.529438 |
| 7 | Botswana pula | nan | 0.0593764 | 0.0595281 | 0.0600917 | 0.0600362 |
| 8 | Brazilian real | nan | 0.148273 | 0.147709 | 0.148393 | 0.151498 |
| 9 | Brunei dollar | nan | 0.548669 | 0.548215 | 0.55085 | 0.54893 |
| 10 | Canadian dollar | nan | 0.586178 | 0.5834 | 0.5861 | 0.586377 |
| 11 | Chilean peso | nan | 0.000856257 | 0.000855312 | 0.000871134 | 0.000860642 |
| 12 | Czech koruna | nan | 0.0313774 | 0.0313768 | 0.0313289 | 0.0312983 |
| 13 | Danish krone | nan | 0.103346 | 0.10332 | 0.103325 | 0.103441 |
| 14 | Indian rupee | nan | 0.0096395 | 0.00967422 | nan | 0.00961806 |
| 15 | Israeli New Shekel | nan | 0.227889 | 0.228331 | 0.230002 | 0.231996 |
| 16 | Korean won | nan | 0.000569131 | 0.000571039 | 0.000570268 | 0.000568929 |
| 17 | Kuwaiti dinar | nan | nan | 2.49425 | 2.49654 | 2.49105 |
| 18 | Malaysian ringgit | nan | 0.171526 | 0.171356 | nan | 0.170977 |
| 19 | Mauritian rupee | nan | 0.0172087 | nan | 0.0171443 | 0.0171741 |
| 20 | Mexican peso | nan | 0.0385038 | 0.0379361 | 0.0382379 | 0.0380585 |
| 21 | New Zealand dollar | nan | 0.466781 | 0.468236 | 0.471167 | 0.47105 |
| 22 | Norwegian krone | nan | 0.0768317 | 0.0767413 | 0.0773168 | 0.0788655 |
| 23 | Omani rial | nan | nan | 1.99767 | 1.99853 | 1.99414 |
| 24 | Peruvian sol | nan | 0.198946 | 0.199042 | 0.200166 | nan |
| 25 | Philippine peso | nan | nan | 0.0136744 | 0.0136628 | 0.0136826 |
| 26 | Polish zloty | nan | 0.162688 | 0.163569 | 0.162254 | 0.162412 |
| 27 | Qatari riyal | nan | nan | 0.211018 | 0.211109 | 0.210645 |
| 28 | Russian ruble | nan | 0.0127399 | 0.0127514 | 0.0127565 | 0.0127013 |
| 29 | Saudi Arabian riyal | nan | nan | 0.204828 | 0.204916 | 0.204466 |
| 30 | Singapore dollar | nan | 0.548669 | 0.548215 | 0.55085 | 0.54893 |
| 31 | South African rand | nan | 0.0444661 | 0.0448438 | 0.0450817 | 0.0455618 |
| 32 | Swedish krona | nan | 0.0715711 | 0.0718351 | 0.0720278 | 0.0718782 |
| 33 | Swiss franc | nan | 0.782903 | 0.78458 | 0.784038 | 0.789442 |
| 34 | Thai baht | nan | 0.0208978 | 0.020927 | 0.0210548 | 0.0210465 |
| 35 | Trinidadian dollar | nan | 0.114475 | 0.114048 | nan | 0.114091 |
| 36 | U.A.E. dirham | nan | nan | 0.20915 | 0.209241 | 0.20878 |
| 37 | Uruguayan peso | nan | 0.0188128 | 0.0188288 | 0.0187606 | 0.0188043 |

​

Relevant documentation:

Requests: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html

BeautifulSoup: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html